# Technical manager vs. Lead programmer

Tags: project-management, management

Can anyone explain the responsibilities of the `Technical manager`and the `Lead programmer`, in team ?

Suppose a medium-size team with about 10-15 persons .

Comment: I think stuff like that varies from team to team.

Comment: I don't think this is specific to game development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varies from team to team.

A `technical manager` can have the responsibility of the planning, execution and closing of any project development.

A `lead programmer`, responsibilities vary from company to company, but in general he or she is responsible for the underlying architecture for the software program, as well as for overseeing the work being done by any other software engineers working on the project. A lead programmer will typically also act as a mentor for new or lower-level software developers or programmers, as well as for all the members on the development team.